# Word cloud generator for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tag-cloud, word-cloud

Is there a Ruby/Rails library that I can generate word clouds (output should be an image file) like in [Wordle.net](http://wordle.net)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why does it have to be a Ruby/Rails library?

You could use [JQCloud](https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud), which is a nice JQuery plugin to build word and tag clouds.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [heatmap](https://github.com/Bantik/heatmap)? There's also a nice blog post explaining it:

http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/guides-tips-and-tutorials/creating-a-heatmap-or-tag-cloud-in-rails

Comment: Yes, the problem is I need more eye-candy results like Wordle does.